# How to stop animation of dragged view?

Tags: android, drag-and-drop, android-7.0-nougat

I have a 2 GridViews, and I can drag items from one to another. But after dropping the view, android plays an animation that moves to the original position of dropped view. Like that: 
[image]

In that example, I dropped top grid item to bottom grid.

I tried to destroy item and DragShadow after dropping it. But it didn't help. 
This animation only plays on devices with Android Nougat OS (24+). So I'm wondering, how can I disable it?

Comment: have you find any solution for it?

Comment: We are also looking for solution, Did you find solution ?

Comment: It's all about View.OnDragListener. In my example, I had OnDragListener only on topGrid. But if I set OnDragListener on both of them, everything works as expected.
I guess, Android thinks that you did't handle drop event, cause view where you dropping item from top doesn't have dragListener

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's all about `View.OnDragListener`. In my example, I had `OnDragListener` only on topGrid. But if I set `OnDragListener` on both of them, everything works as expected. I guess, Android thinks that you did't handle drop event, cause view where you dropping item from top doesn't have dragListener

Answer (score 0):

This to clarify the prior answer.  If you want to get rid to the animation that occurs upon drop, then set an OnDragListener that does nothing on the activity's content view:

```
View theContentView = theContext.findViewById(android.R.id.content);
theContentView.setOnDragListener(xxx);
```

Where xxx is a OnDragListener whose onDrag(...) method does nothing except to return TRUE.